# Rust split Vec<u8> into a struct of arrays of certain lengths

Tags: arrays, rust, vector, struct

So I have a bytecode file that is made up of 32 sectors of 4KiB of data that I wanted to store in a struct like this, I was able to get the `u16` and `u32` values to work. I'm only having trouble turning the chunks of the Vec<u8> that was generated from the file into the arrays.

```rust
struct Sector {
    data: [u8; 3968],
    unused: [u8; 116],
    id: u16,
    checksum: u16,
    signature: u32,
    counter: u32,
}
```

This is my current attempt, and I don't know what to do to split the two chunks into their respective arrays and would like help.

```rust
for sect in 0..32 {
    let offset = 4096 * sect;
    sect_vec.push(Sector{
        data: buffer[(0 + offset)..=(3967 + offset)].try_into(),
        unused: buffer[(3968 + offset)..=(4083 + offset)].try_into(),
        id: u16::from_le_bytes([buffer[4084 + offset], buffer[4085 + offset]]),
        checksum: u16::from_le_bytes([buffer[4086 + offset], buffer[4087 + offset]]),
        signature: u32::from_le_bytes([buffer[4088 + offset], buffer[4089 + offset], buffer[4090 + offset], buffer[4091 + offset]]),
        counter: u32::from_le_bytes([buffer[4092 + offset], buffer[4093 + offset], buffer[4094 + offset], buffer[4095 + offset]]),
    });
}
```

```
   |
47 |             unused: buffer[(3968 + offset)..=(4083 + offset)].try_into(),
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `[u8; 116]`, found `Result<_, _>`
   |
   = note: expected array `[u8; 116]`
               found enum `Result<_, _>`
```

Comment: The duplicate applied to your question: `try_into` returns a `Result` since conversion may fail, in which case you need to handle the error. Easiest is to just `unwrap` it with `….try_into().unwrap()` to get at the underlying value or abort in case of error.